# python callback syntax error in Scapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I've got the following code which i'm trying to run. I'm getting a python invalid syntax error. I'm using Mac with python 2.7.10. Is there anything wrong? I'm relatively new to python

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
callback='parse_item',

full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import Linkextractors

class MpuDivsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mpu_divs'
    allowed_domains = ['www.capitalfm.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.capitalfm.com/']

#http://www.capitalfm.com/music-news/kylie-jenner-outcast-not-made-for-fame/
#http://www.capitalfm.com/artists/adele/news/grenfell-kids-cinema/
#http://www.capitalfm.com/music-news/week-photos/7-august-2017/justin-bieber/
#http://www.capitalfm.com/music-news/week-photos/7-august-2017/leigh-anne-pinnock/
    rules = [

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'/7-august-2017/\w*'])
        callback='parse_item',
        follow = True)
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print response.url
```

Comment: Put a comma `,` at the end of `Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'/7-august-2017/\w*'])`

Comment: thanks, can't believe I forgot that

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a `,` at the end of line `19`:

```
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'/7-august-2017/\w*']),
```

Comment: I can't believe I forget that, such a simple error. Thanks